# wait процессов, запущенных в другом потоке; clone и CLONE_PARENT

Tags: linux, c, syscall

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
static char child_stack[1048576];
char* chroot_cmd = 0;
static int child_fn(void* _st) {
    fork_st* st = (fork_st*)_st;
  printf("PPID: %ld\n", (long)getppid());
  return execl(st->file,st->arg,NULL);
}

int fork_exec(const char* file,const char* arg) {
    fork_st* st = new fork_st;
    st->file = file;
    st->arg = arg;
  pid_t child_pid = clone(child_fn, child_stack+1048576, CLONE_VM | CLONE_PARENT | SIGCHLD, static_cast<void*>(st));
  printf("clone() = %ld\n", (long)child_pid);
  waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0);
  return 0;
}
...
int pid2 = fork();
if(pid2 <=0) { вызовы fork_exec }
,,,
int waitres = waitpid(-1,&status,0);
    while(waitres >= 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "PID: " << waitres << " signal: " << status << std::endl;
        waitres = waitpid(-1,&status,0);
    }
```

Задача кода - вызвать процесс с флагом CLONE_PARENT, т.е. сохранением родителя. В родительском процессе работает wait() на всех дочерних процессов, а сами дочерние процессы вызываются из другого потока, что делает необходимым использование CLONE_PARENT. Если не использовать CLONE_PARENT wait не подхватит процесс и он останется зомби.
**Вопрос 1**:  Как переделать код так, что бы эта функция могла работать на несколько вызовов. Я вижу пока только 2 решения:
1. Отказатся от child_stack и предоставить ядру самому выделить память(тогда как передать структуру fork_st)
2. Каким то образом освободить child_stack после вызова exec. (как? и можно так делать?)
**Вопрос 2**: Есть ли аналог epoll_wait для процессов?
**Вопрос 3**: Можно ли заставить wait работать с процессами, вызванными в другом потоке той же программы, и как в таком случае должна выглядеть функция fork_exec

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось куда проще. Я использовал fork что бы сымитировать работу потоков, и из за этого wait не видел процессов, запущенных внутри "потока". Вопрос с epoll_wait для процессов, и CLONE_PARENT остается открытым

```
int fork_exec(const char* file,const char* arg)
{
    int pid = vfork();
    if(pid<=0)
    {
        execl(file,file, arg,NULL);
        _exit(0);
    }
    return pid;
}
```